# How to do Erlang pattern matching using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, string, erlang, text-parsing

When I write Erlang programs which do text parsing, I frequently run into situations where I would love to do a pattern match using a regular expression.

For example, I wish I could do something like this, where ~ is a "made up" regular expression matching operator:

```
my_function(String ~ ["^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*$"]) ->
    ....
```

I know about the regular expression module (re) but AFAIK you cannot call functions when pattern matching or in guards.

Also, I wish matching strings could be done in a case-insensitive way. This is handy, for example, when parsing HTTP headers, I would love to do something like this where "Str ~ {Pattern, Options}" means "Match Str against pattern Pattern using options Options":

```
handle_accept_language_header(Header ~ {"Accept-Language", [case_insensitive]}) ->
    ...
```

Two questions:

1. How do you typically handle this using just standard Erlang? Is there some mechanism / coding style which comes close to this in terms of conciseness and easiness to read?
2. Is there any work (an EEP?) going on in Erlang to address this?

Comment: I doubt an EEP to add regular expressions as patterns would be supported. All current patterns can be evaluated in constant time, regexps can't. (length/1 is perhaps the only exception to the constant time rule)

Answer (score 7):

You really don't have much choice other than to run your regexps in advance and then pattern match on the results. Here's a very simple example that approaches what I think you're after, but it does suffer from the flaw that you need to repeat the regexps twice. You could make this less painful by using a macro to define each regexp in one place.

```
-module(multire).

-compile(export_all).

multire([],_) ->
    nomatch;
multire([RE|RegExps],String) ->
    case re:run(String,RE,[{capture,none}]) of
    match ->
        RE;
    nomatch ->
        multire(RegExps,String)
    end.


test(Foo) ->
    test2(multire(["^Hello","world$","^....$"],Foo),Foo).

test2("^Hello",Foo) ->
    io:format("~p matched the hello pattern~n",[Foo]);
test2("world$",Foo) ->
    io:format("~p matched the world pattern~n",[Foo]);
test2("^....$",Foo) ->
    io:format("~p matched the four chars pattern~n",[Foo]);
test2(nomatch,Foo) ->
    io:format("~p failed to match~n",[Foo]).
```

Answer (score 6):

A possibility could be to use *Erlang Web-style* annotations (macros) combined with the *re* Erlang module. An example is probably the best way to illustrate this.

This is how your final code will look like:

```
[...]
?MATCH({Regexp, Options}).
foo(_Args) ->
  ok.
[...]
```

The *MATCH* macro would be executed just before your *foo* function. The flow of execution will fail if the regexp pattern is not matched.

Your match function will be declared as follows:

```
?BEFORE.
match({Regexp, Options}, TgtMod, TgtFun, TgtFunArgs) ->
String = proplists:get_value(string, TgtArgs),
case re:run(String, Regexp, Options) of
  nomatch ->
    {error, {TgtMod, match_error, []}};
  {match, _Captured} ->
    {proceed, TgtFunArgs}
end.
```

Please note that:

- The *BEFORE* says that macro will be executed before your target function (AFTER macro is also available).
- The match_error is your error handler, specified in your module, and contains the code you want to execute if you fail a match (maybe nothing, just block the execution flow)
- This approach has the advantage of keeping the regexp syntax and options uniform with the *re* module (avoid confusion).

More information about the Erlang Web annotations here:

> http://wiki.erlang-web.org/Annotations

and here:

> http://wiki.erlang-web.org/HowTo/CreateAnnotation

The software is open source, so you might want to reuse their annotation engine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the re module:

```
re:run(String, "^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*$").
re:run(String, "^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*$", [caseless]).
```

EDIT:

```
match(String, Regexps) -> 
  case lists:dropwhile(
               fun({Regexp, Opts}) -> re:run(String, Regexp, Opts) =:= nomatch;
                  (Regexp) -> re:run(String, Regexp) =:= nomatch end,
               Regexps) of
    [R|_] -> R;
    _     -> nomatch
  end.

example(String) ->
  Regexps = ["$RE1^", {"$RE2^", [caseless]}, "$RE3"]
  case match(String, Regexps) of
    nomatch -> handle_error();
    Regexp -> handle_regexp(String, Regexp)
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, the re module does a great job at regular expressions, but you AFAIK you cannot call functions while pattern matching or in guards.

Comment: If I only understood what you mean by pattern matching... should Erlang make-up a regular expression for you that matches the string, or what?

Comment: I think what he would like is something like an is_match(RegExp,S) bif for use in guards, so:
foo(X) when is_match(RE1,X) ->
  one_thing();
foo(X) when is_match(RE2,X) ->
  another_thing().
etc.

Comment: OK, I added an example of what could be done, if that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

1. For string, you could use the 're' module : afterwards, you iterate over the result set. I am afraid there isn't another way to do it AFAIK: that's why there are regexes.
2. For the HTTP headers, since there can be many, I would consider iterating over the result set to be a better option **instead** of writing a very long expression (potentially).
3. EEP work : I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

1. Erlang does not handle regular expressions in patterns.
2. No.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pattern match on regular expressions, sorry. So you have to do

```
my_function(String) -> Matches = re:run(String, "^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*$"),
                       ...
```